# Define redundant task options centrally and reuse them in different tasks

Tags: ansible, yaml

**Is it possible to define task options centrally to reuse them in different tasks?**

I am currently working with several [community.postgresql](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/index.html#modules) modules, like `postgresql_db`, `postgresql_user` and `postgresql_privs`. I always have to define the options `login_host`, `port`, `login_user`, `login_password`, but these are the same the whole execution, so I would like to define them once centrally and just include each.

So far my tasks look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Create database
  community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ pg_db_name }}"

    login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
    port: "{{ pg_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
    login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"

- name: Create database user
  community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
    name: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
    password: "{{ pg_user.password }}"

    login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
    port: "{{ pg_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
    login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"

- name: Set user privileges on database
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    database: "{{ pg_db_name }}"
    roles: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
    privs: ALL
    type: database

    login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
    port: "{{ pg_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
    login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"
```

I thought I could implement the whole thing via [YAML Merge](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, I always get the following error message:

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: login_host, login_user

My attempt to implement it using YAML Merge looks like this:

```yaml
- &pg_connect {
    login_host: "{{ pg_host }}",
    port: "{{ pg_port }}",
    login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}",
    login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"
  }

- name: Create database
  community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
    << : *pg_connect
    name: "{{ pg_db_name }}"


- name: Create database user
  community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
    << : *pg_connect
    name: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
    password: "{{ pg_user.password }}"

- name: Set user privileges on database
  community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
    << : *pg_connect
    database: "{{ pg_db_name }}"
    roles: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
    privs: ALL
    type: database
```

Is there a (simple) solution in Ansible to save these redundant lines?

---

I have now tested with the `module_defaults` variant for some time, but have encountered the following problem.

I tested with a minimal playbook to avoid side effects as much as possible.

- `pg_connect_modules` definition tested as static definition in the `vars` area of the playbook (like the example) and at runtime via `set_fact`.
- `pg_connect` is defined at runtime via `set_fact`, in all testing scenarios.
- The `module_defaults` definition of task **Create database No 1** works without problems.
- The `module_defaults` definition of task **Create database No 2** always leads to the following error - whereby the playbook execution cannot be started at all, the error appears directly.

  > `ansible-playbook -i inventory play.yml`
  > ERROR! The field 'module_defaults' is supposed to be a dictionary or list of dictionaries, the keys of which must be static action, module, or group names. Only the values may contain templates. For example: {'ping': "{{ ping_defaults }}"}
- I can start the playbook execution at all only if I comment out the task **Create database No 2** or at least the `module_defaults` line of this task.
- If I have the database tasks in a tasks file and I include them via `include_tasks`, the include fails; the playbook executes up to that point and then the include fails with the same error.

My playbook looks like this:

```yaml
play.yml
---

- hosts: testserver
  become: yes

  vars:
    pg_connect_modules:
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        login_host: "localhost"
        port: "5432"
        login_user: "postgres_admin"
        login_password: "myPass"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        pg_connect: "{{ common_defaults }}"
      vars:
        common_defaults:
          login_host: "localhost"
          port: "5432"
          login_user: "postgres_admin"
          login_password: "myPass"

    - name: Create database No 1
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: "test1"
      module_defaults:
        community.postgresql.postgresql_db: "{{ pg_connect }}"

    - name: Create database No 2
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: "test1"
      module_defaults: "{{ pg_connect_modules }}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At any [level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) (play, role, block, task) you can use [*module_defaults*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults). For example, in a block

```yaml
- block:

    - name: Create database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: "{{ pg_db_name }}"

    - name: Create database user
      community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
        name: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
        password: "{{ pg_user.password }}"

    - name: Set user privileges on database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
        database: "{{ pg_db_name }}"
        roles: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
        privs: ALL
        type: database

  module_defaults:
    community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
      login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
      port: "{{ pg_port }}"
      login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
      login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"
    community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
      login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
      port: "{{ pg_port }}"
      login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
      login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"
    community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
      login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
      port: "{{ pg_port }}"
      login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
      login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"
```

It's practical to combine and declare the dictionary *module_defaults* outside the code. For example, in the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/my_defaults.yml
my_module_defaults_list:
  - modules:
      - community.postgresql.postgresql_db
      - community.postgresql.postgresql_user
      - community.postgresql.postgresql_privs
    defaults:
      login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
      port: "{{ pg_port }}"
      login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
      login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"

my_module_defaults_str: |
  {% for i in my_module_defaults_list %}
  {{ dict(i.modules|product([i.defaults])) }}
  {% endfor %}
my_module_defaults: "{{ my_module_defaults_str|from_yaml }}"
```

given the variables below

```yaml
  pg_host: pb.example.com
  pg_port: 5432
  pg_admin:
    username: admin
    password: admin_passwd
```

The dictionary gives

```yaml
  my_module_defaults:
    community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
      login_host: pb.example.com
      login_password: admin_passwd
      login_user: admin
      port: 5432
    community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
      login_host: pb.example.com
      login_password: admin_passwd
      login_user: admin
      port: 5432
    community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
      login_host: pb.example.com
      login_password: admin_passwd
      login_user: admin
      port: 5432
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use it directly in a play. For some reason, the keys of the dictionary must be static

```yaml
- block:

    - name: Create database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: "{{ pg_db_name }}"

    - name: Create database user
      community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
        name: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
        password: "{{ pg_user.password }}"

    - name: Set user privileges on database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
        database: "{{ pg_db_name }}"
        roles: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
        privs: ALL
        type: database

  module_defaults: "{{ my_module_defaults }}"
```

The above code will cause the error:

> ERROR! The field 'module_defaults' is supposed to be a dictionary or list of dictionaries, the keys of which must be static action, module, or group names. Only the values may contain templates. For example: {'ping': "{{ ping_defaults }}"}

As a workaround, you can create the below template

```yaml
shell> cat postgresql.yml.j2
- block:

    - name: Create database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: "{{ pg_db_name }}"

    - name: Create database user
      community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
        name: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
        password: "{{ pg_user.password }}"

    - name: Set user privileges on database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
        database: "{{ pg_db_name }}"
        roles: "{{ pg_user.username }}"
        privs: ALL
        type: database

  module_defaults:
{{ my_module_defaults|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(4, first=true) }}
```

and include the created file in the play

```yaml
    - template:
        src: postgresql.yml.j2
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/postgresql.yml"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      tags: build
    - include_tasks: postgresql.yml
```

---

```yaml
shell> cat postgresql.yml
- block:

    - name: Create database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
        name: "db_01"

    - name: Create database user
      community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
        name: "user"
        password: "user_passwd"

    - name: Set user privileges on database
      community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
        database: "db_01"
        roles: "user"
        privs: ALL
        type: database

  module_defaults:
    community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
      login_host: pb.example.com
      login_password: admin_passwd
      login_user: admin
      port: 5432
    community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
      login_host: pb.example.com
      login_password: admin_passwd
      login_user: admin
      port: 5432
    community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
      login_host: pb.example.com
      login_password: admin_passwd
      login_user: admin
      port: 5432
```

---

The proper solution is to create [Module defaults group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults-groups). There is no group declared in the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/community.postgresql/main/meta/runtime.yml) atm. You can create it. For example, find out the path to your collections and create the group

```yaml
shell> cat ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/meta/runtime.yml 
---
requires_ansible: '>=2.9.10'
action_groups:
  postgresql:
    - postgresql_db
    - postgresql_privs
    - postgresql_user
```

Then the block below should work as expected

```yaml
    - block:

        - name: Create database
          community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
            name: "db_01"

        - name: Create database user
          community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
            name: "user"
            password: "user_passwd"

        - name: Set user privileges on database
          community.postgresql.postgresql_privs:
            database: "db_01"
            roles: "user"
            privs: ALL
            type: database

      module_defaults:
        group/community.postgresql.postgresql:
          login_host: pb.example.com
          login_password: admin_passwd
          login_user: admin
          port: 5432
```

You can open a [request](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.postgresql/issues) if you want to. It will be necessary to review the consistency of all parameters of all postgresql modules and create the group(s).

---

Notes:

- In a mission-critical environment provide the *login_password* in a limited scope. See [Ansible passing vault password file to playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570424/ansible-passing-vault-password-file-to-playbook/63573074#63573074).
- If you want to use *module_defaults* at a play level the dictionary must be available in this scope. See [Ansible, module_defaults and package module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517066/ansible-module-defaults-and-package-module/64521988#64521988) (obsolete; broken in 2.12).
- Quoting from *CHANGELOG-v2.12.rst Breaking Changes: "Action, module, and group names in module_defaults must be static values. Their values can still be templates."*

Example of a complete playbook for testing the error and the workaround

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_module_defaults:
      debug:
        msg: common default

    debug_defaults:
      msg: common default

  tasks:

    - name: Work as expected
      debug:
      module_defaults:
        debug: "{{ debug_defaults }}"
      
#    - name: ERROR
#      debug:
#      module_defaults: "{{ my_module_defaults }}"
#
# ERROR! The field 'module_defaults' is supposed to be a dictionary or
# list of dictionaries, the keys of which must be static action, module,
# or group names. Only the values may contain templates. For example:
# {'ping': "{{ ping_defaults }}"}

    - name: Workaround
      template:
        src: my_module.yml.j2
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/my_module.yml"
    - include_tasks: my_module.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat my_module.yml.j2
- block:

    - debug:

  module_defaults:
{{ my_module_defaults|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(4, first=true) }}
```

```yaml
shell> cat my_module.yml
- block:

    - debug:

  module_defaults:
    debug:
      msg: common default
```

Comment: `module_defaults` is very interesting, I didn`t know this feature before. Thanks for pointing out this possibility.

Comment: I have defined a variable `my_module_defaults` using `set_fact`. `- debug: var=my_module_defaults` returns a result like your above, a dict with module identifiers as keys and value is again a dict with the options. -- But using `module_defaults:"{{ my_module_defaults }}"` seems to be impossible. I always get the error message: «ERROR! The field 'module_defaults' is supposed to be a dictionary or list of dictionaries, the keys of which must be static action, module, or group names. Only the values may contain templates.»

Comment: If, instead of passing the variable `my_module_defaults` to `module_defaults`, I statically define the keys for `module_defaults`, and then assign a variable for each key (postgresql module identifier), then it works. - I am not sure if I did something wrong, but I cannot see any mistake.

Comment: Seems like the variable *my_module_defaults* didn't expand properly. Probably any substitute was missing? Put a debug right before the block and show the value of *my_module_defaults*. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Localize the problem. Start with a single module and a single parameter.

Comment: I have now extended my post, with example and description.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're right. *module_defaults* works with static keys only. I added a workaround and described the proper solution of adding the 'module default group'.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Ansible is basically very flexible, did you find out why only static keys are allowed at this point?

Comment: See [CHANGELOG-v2.12.rst#breaking-changes-porting-guide](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.12/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.12.rst#breaking-changes-porting-guide). It's pretty annoying they decided to break it. I didn't know until you pointed it out. [It was working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517066/ansible-module-defaults-and-package-module/64521988#64521988). They expect each collection to provide a 'module default group'. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set_fact` taks in order to define your YAML anchor:

```yaml
- name: Registering common settings for Postgres tasks 
  set_fact:
    pg_connect: &pg_connect
      login_host: "{{ pg_host }}"
      port: "{{ pg_port }}"
      login_user: "{{ pg_admin.username }}"
      login_password: "{{ pg_admin.password }}"
```

Then use the overrides like you tried:

```yaml
- name: Create database
  community.postgresql.postgresql_db:
    <<: *pg_connect
    name: "{{ pg_db_name }}"
```

Comment: That's very interesting how the YAML syntax fits into Ansible, using the set_fact module for that.