# How to fix deprecation error about DEFAULT_GATHER_SUBSET in ansible?

Tags: ansible, warnings

```ini
ansible [core 2.14.2]
python version = 3.11.2
jinja version = 3.1.2
```

I have this in `ansible.cfg`

```ini
[defaults]

roles_path = roles

callback_plugins = plugins/callback
filter_plugins = plugins/filter

interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3

ansible_managed = Ansible managed. All changes will be lost. Please edit in ansible playbook only.

callbacks_enabled = profile_tasks,profile_roles,timer

timeout = 240
gathering = explicit
gather_subset = min
```

I receive this annoying warning

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: DEFAULT_GATHER_SUBSET option, the module_defaults keyword is a more generic version and can apply to all calls to the M(ansible.builtin.gather_facts) or M(ansible.builtin.setup) actions, use
> module_defaults instead. This feature will be removed from ansible-core in version 2.18. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

I don't want to mute deprecation (using `deprecation_warnings=False`), but I want to fix this warning correctly

How can I do that?

P.S. I need to use this setting in `ansible.cfg`, not in playbooks directly.

Comment: According your requirements "_I don't want to mute deprecation_", "_I need to use this setting in `ansible.cfg`_" and "_I want to fix this warning correctly_" this will probably leave you with change the Ansible code directly. Maybe in `display.py`. Please take note that that would only suppress the specific deprecation warning message, the main cause and reason will not be addressed and the problem becomes bigger but only later. Therefore it is recommended to address it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.18 and later you won't be able to configure [*DEFAULT_GATHER_SUBSET*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.14/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.14.rst#deprecated-features). Since 2.18 you will have to use the keyword [*module_defaults*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults) to configure the default value of [*gather_subset*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-module-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) of the module [*setup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-module-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts).

Instead of configuring *DEFAULT_GATHER_SUBSET* in *ansible.cfg*

```ini
gather_subset = min
```

You will have to declare the [*keyword*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) [*module_defaults*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults), for example at the play level

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  module_defaults:
    ansible.builtin.setup:
      gather_subset: min
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Can i use this config in `ansible.cfg`? I don't want to change my playbooks (
Only in one place

Comment: No, you can't use *keywords* in the configuration and it's getting even worse. [*The keys (names of the modules) must be static!*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.12/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.12.rst#breaking-changes--porting-guide). This means, you can't create the dictionary, for example, in *group_vars/all* and use it. You have to explicitly declare *module_defaults* in each play! (If you want to use it). The only workaround seems to be some kind of dynamic playbook from a template.

Comment: See [Define redundant task options centrally and reuse them in different tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75306738/6482561).