# Ansible keeps giving an error about variable being undefined

Tags: ansible

I am trying to eliminate the need for plaintext passwords in Ansible .yml files. I have been successful in hooking up to an Azure Key Vault for individual tasks with the following:

```yaml
- name: Execute install command on remote Windows host as localadmin  
  hosts: workstations
  become: true
  become_user: localadmin
  tasks:
    - name: Run install .bat file
      win_command: C:\Users\Public\install.bat
  vars:
    url: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.vault.azure.net/'
    secretname: 'localadmin'
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    tenant: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    admin_password: "{{ lookup('azure_keyvault_secret', secretname, vault_url=url, client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant_id=tenant) }}"
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ admin_password }}"
```

The problem is I need to specify this for every task. I don't want to have to repeat this code for every task. I want to place it in single spot and then refer to the "{{ admin_password }}"

There is a file that can be accessed globally that defines the passwords like this:

```yaml
default_local_admin:
  username: localadmin
  password: InSecurePasswordInPlainText
```

It is then referenced in other files as default_local_admin.password

I want to do something like this:

```yaml
default_local_admin:
  username: localadmin
  password: "{{ admin_password }}"
```

I am trying to break this down into small steps. As a first step, I am only trying to define a variable and assign the password to that. Once I get that working, I will work on the Key Vault part. No matter how I try defining "admin_password", I get an error saying it is undefined.

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.

How do I define this?

I have tried the following, but they don't work;

```yaml
default_local_admin:
  admin_password: InSecurePasswordInPlainText
  username: localadmin
  password: "{{ admin_password }}"
```

```yaml
default_local_admin:
  vars:
    admin_password: InSecurePasswordInPlainText
  username: localadmin
  password: "{{ admin_password }}"
```

```yaml
# At the top of the file 
  vars:
    admin_password: InSecurePasswordInPlainText
```

```yaml
# At the top of the file 
  admin_password: InSecurePasswordInPlainText
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define redundant task options centrally and reuse them in different tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304438/define-redundant-task-options-centrally-and-reuse-them-in-different-tasks)