# How can I create an Ansible role wrapper with variable passthough

Tags: ansible

I want to encapsulate a role without defining all input variables, just like python `*args, **kwargs`.

In my example, I'm using pipx to install globally a package (ansible itself):

`playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Install ansible with sudo pipx
      become: yes
      environment:
        PIPX_HOME: /opt/pipx
        PIPX_BIN_DIR: /usr/local/bin
      community.general.pipx:
        name: ansible
        state: present
        install_deps: true
```

### What I have:

I can create a task that wraps this behaviour, but I have to explicitly declare all variables that I'm going to use:

`playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Install ansible with sudo pipx
      include_tasks: my_custom_sudo_pipx.yml
      vars:
        name: ansible
        state: present
        install_deps: true
```

`my_custom_sudo_pipx.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Sudo pipx
  become: yes
  environment:
    PIPX_HOME: /opt/pipx
    PIPX_BIN_DIR: /usr/local/bin
  community.general.pipx:
    #  what i do not like to do:
    name: "{{ name }}"
    state: "{{ state }}"
    install_deps: "{{ install_deps }}"
```

### What I want:

Ideally, I would like to reuse this task without repeating the environment variables, but allowing inputting all `community.general.pipx` expected variables:

`playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Install ansible with sudo pipx
      include_tasks: my_custom_sudo_pipx.yml
      vars:
        name: ansible
        state: present
        install_deps: true
```

`my_custom_sudo_pipx.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Sudo pipx
  become: yes
  environment:
    PIPX_HOME: /opt/pipx
    PIPX_BIN_DIR: /usr/local/bin
  community.general.pipx:
    {{ all_input_vars }}       # this is what I dont know how to do
```

How can I make this input variable passthrough, **without explicitly defining** all `ansible.community.pipx` variables.

Comment: Your question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304438/define-redundant-task-options-centrally-and-reuse-them-in-different-tasks/75306738#75306738 to me.

Comment: Not exactly, It could work but I do not want to lose the ability to use the original task. I want to create a separate module, like a inherited class

Comment: Then use a YAML anchor as proposed by the other answer. What you are looking to do was possible at some point with `args` but, as far as I know, is now forbidden due to obvious reasons that you can end up including uncontrolled parameters.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it is forbidden?